# How to Dockerize an API which has a reference to another project whitin the same solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

I have a solution named PostalCode which includes three projects; a class library named PostalCode.Core that serves as the core of the solution and includes database, models and services. an API named PostalCode.API which has a reference to the Core and uses it's services. the last one is an MVC named PostalCode.MVC which is referred to as the UI and has reference to the API project and consumes the endpoint. I have no problem Dockerizing the MVC project. I added a Dockerfile to the root of the project with the code below and it worked

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4420

# Use the official SDK image to build the project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "PostalCode.MVC.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "PostalCode.MVC.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Final image with published output
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PostalCode.MVC.dll"]
```

But when I add the same for the API project with replacing PostalCode.MVC with PostalCode.API, I got the error below

```
    ERROR [build 5/5] RUN dotnet publish "PostalCode.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 50ec7a5e-e296-49d7-87c1-66dffd6e00da::go8tj6phckvpcr0ab9qaxo4z9: "/PostalCode.API/PostalCode.API.csproj": not found
```

What's wrong with the code? Should I include a reference to the Core project as I'm writing Dockerfile for the API?

Comment: The UI should not have a reference to the API

Comment: Also, you haven't actually given us the full error message, we need to see more.

Comment: @DavidG It has nothing to do with the topic being discussed. My question is about dockerizing the API which has a reference to the Core project

Comment: I agree with @DavidG -- please take a moment and include the entire error message and any associated detail.

Comment: @DavidTansey Post was updated with the full details of the error.

Comment: It is not easy to tell for sure, but it looks to me like a pathing problem.  You have only showed us the DockerFile code for the MVC project (which is working as expected) and then you describe how you modified it for the API project (but do not show the related DockerFile code).  The error message seems to indicate that it cannot find your CSPROJ file for the API project.  I would troubleshoot the `dotnet publish` command directly on the command line to figure out your pathing problem.